# how can i send post request using slider Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to send a post request every time I change the value of the slider but I dont know how to do it, is it even possible? I can only POST when I click a button.

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import random

app = Flask(__name__)


def generate_arr():
    return [random.randrange(1, 700, 1) for _ in range(10)]


def arr_len(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    return length


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html", content=generate_arr(), len=arr_len(generate_arr()))


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def generate():
    if request.method == "POST":
        size = request.form["slide"]
        arr = [random.randrange(1, 700, 1) for _ in range(int(size))]
        length = len(arr)
        return render_template("index.html", content=arr, len=length)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html:

```
 <form action="#" method="post">

        <div>
            <button name="genBtn" type="submit">Generate</button>
            <input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" name="slide">

        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript

Comment: Try sending an Ajax request using Javascript (or jQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript (fetch api or jquery) to send a post request to your web server with the data from the slider.

Comment: thanks bro I'll just search how it works <3